# Segmentation fault in Vulkan on vkMapMemory call / (device.map_memory in Erupt)

Tags: rust, vulkan

I'm using Rust and the Rust-based Vulkan wrapper Erupt.

Everything in this code runs fine until the `device.map_memory` call.  No VulkanValidation warnings or errors are raised.  Just a segmentation fault.  I have offsets set to zero, but this is the only memory usage of this buffer, so I'm not sure if the issue is offsets or something else.

```rust
use memoffset::offset_of;
use simple_logger::SimpleLogger;
use winit::{
    event::{
        Event, KeyboardInput, WindowEvent, 
        ElementState, StartCause, VirtualKeyCode
    },
    event_loop::{ControlFlow, EventLoop},
    window::WindowBuilder,
    window::Window         
};
// use winit::event::{ElementState, StartCause, VirtualKeyCode};
use structopt::StructOpt;

use erupt::{
    cstr,
    utils::{self, surface},
    vk, DeviceLoader, EntryLoader, InstanceLoader,
};

use std::{
    ffi::{c_void, CStr, CString},
    mem::*,
    os::raw::c_char,
    ptr,
    result::Result,
    result::Result::*,
    string::String,
    thread,
    time,
};


use raw_window_handle::{HasRawWindowHandle, RawWindowHandle};

const TITLE: &str = "Peregrine Ray-Trace";
const FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT: usize = 2;
const LAYER_KHRONOS_VALIDATION: *const c_char = cstr!("VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation");

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
struct Opt {
    /// Use validation layers
    #[structopt(short, long)]
    validation_layers: bool,
}


unsafe extern "system" fn debug_callback(
    _message_severity: vk::DebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT,
    _message_types: vk::DebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT,
    p_callback_data: *const vk::DebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT,
    _p_user_data: *mut c_void,
) -> vk::Bool32 {
    eprintln!(
        "Vulkan: {}",
        CStr::from_ptr((*p_callback_data).p_message).to_string_lossy()
    );
    vk::FALSE
}


#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct VertexV3 {
    pos: [f32; 4],
    color: [f32; 4],
}
impl VertexV3 {
    fn get_binding_descriptions() -> [vk::VertexInputBindingDescription; 1] {
        [vk::VertexInputBindingDescription {
            binding: 0,
            stride: std::mem::size_of::<Self>() as u32,
            input_rate: vk::VertexInputRate::VERTEX,
        }]
    }

    pub fn get_attribute_descriptions() -> [vk::VertexInputAttributeDescription; 2] {
        [
            vk::VertexInputAttributeDescription {
                binding: 0,
                location: 0,
                format: vk::Format::R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT,
                offset: offset_of!(Self, pos) as u32,
            },
            vk::VertexInputAttributeDescription {
                binding: 0,
                location: 1,
                format: vk::Format::R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT,
                offset: offset_of!(Self, color) as u32,
            },
        ]
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Ray-Peregrine Lab 24::::!!!!");
    let mut vulkan_output = String::from("");
    println!("Ray-EE-Oct-12");

    let event_loop = EventLoop::new();
    let window = WindowBuilder::new()
        .with_title("Peregrine Ray-Trace")
        .build(&event_loop)
        .unwrap();

    let entry = EntryLoader::new().unwrap();

    // https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Instance
    let application_name = CString::new("Peregrine Ray-Trace").unwrap();
    
    let engine_name = CString::new("Vulkan Engine").unwrap();
    let app_info = vk::ApplicationInfoBuilder::new()
        .application_name(&application_name)
        .application_version(vk::make_api_version(0, 1, 0, 0))
        .engine_name(&engine_name)
        .engine_version(vk::make_api_version(0, 1, 0, 0))
        .api_version(vk::make_api_version(0, 1, 0, 0));

    let mut instance_extensions = surface::enumerate_required_extensions(&window).unwrap();

    instance_extensions.push(vk::EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME);
    let mut instance_layers = Vec::new();
    instance_layers.push(LAYER_KHRONOS_VALIDATION);

    let device_extensions = vec![
        vk::KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME, 
        vk::KHR_RAY_TRACING_PIPELINE_EXTENSION_NAME,
        vk::KHR_RAY_QUERY_EXTENSION_NAME,
        vk::KHR_DEFERRED_HOST_OPERATIONS_EXTENSION_NAME,
        vk::KHR_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_EXTENSION_NAME,
        vk::KHR_SPIRV_1_4_EXTENSION_NAME,
    ];

    let mut device_layers = Vec::new();

    device_layers.push(LAYER_KHRONOS_VALIDATION);

    let instance_info = vk::InstanceCreateInfoBuilder::new()
        .application_info(&app_info)
        .enabled_extension_names(&instance_extensions)
        .enabled_layer_names(&instance_layers);

    let instance = unsafe { InstanceLoader::new(&entry, &instance_info, None) }.unwrap();

    // https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers
    // if opt.validation_layers ...

    let messenger = {
        let messenger_info = vk::DebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXTBuilder::new()
            .message_severity(
                vk::DebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagsEXT::VERBOSE_EXT
                    | vk::DebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagsEXT::WARNING_EXT
                    | vk::DebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagsEXT::ERROR_EXT,
            )
            .message_type(
                vk::DebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT::GENERAL_EXT
                    | vk::DebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT::VALIDATION_EXT
                    | vk::DebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT::PERFORMANCE_EXT,
            )
            .pfn_user_callback(Some(debug_callback));

        unsafe { instance.create_debug_utils_messenger_ext(&messenger_info, None) }.unwrap()
    };

    let surface = unsafe { surface::create_surface(&instance, &window, None) }.unwrap();

    let (physical_device, queue_family, format, present_mode, device_properties) =
        unsafe { instance.enumerate_physical_devices(None) }
            .unwrap()
            .into_iter()
            .filter_map(|physical_device| unsafe {
                // println!("Physical Device: {:?}", physical_device);
                // println!("Phyisical Device Queue Family Properties: {:?}", instance.get_physical_device_properties(physical_device));
                let queue_family = match instance
                    .get_physical_device_queue_family_properties(physical_device, None)
                    .into_iter()
                    .enumerate()
                    .position(|(i, queue_family_properties)| {
                        queue_family_properties
                            .queue_flags
                            .contains(vk::QueueFlags::GRAPHICS)
                            && instance
                                .get_physical_device_surface_support_khr(
                                    physical_device,
                                    i as u32,
                                    surface,
                                )
                                .unwrap()
                    }) {
                    Some(queue_family) => queue_family as u32,
                    None => return None,
                };

                let formats = instance
                    .get_physical_device_surface_formats_khr(physical_device, surface, None)
                    .unwrap();
                let format = match formats
                    .iter()
                    .find(|surface_format| {
                        surface_format.format == vk::Format::B8G8R8A8_SRGB
                            && surface_format.color_space == vk::ColorSpaceKHR::SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR
                    })
                    .or_else(|| formats.get(0))
                {
                    Some(surface_format) => *surface_format,
                    None => return None,
                };


                let present_mode = instance
                    .get_physical_device_surface_present_modes_khr(physical_device, surface, None)
                    .unwrap()
                    .into_iter()
                    .find(|present_mode| present_mode == &vk::PresentModeKHR::MAILBOX_KHR)
                    .unwrap_or(vk::PresentModeKHR::FIFO_KHR);

                let supported_device_extensions = instance
                    .enumerate_device_extension_properties(physical_device, None, None)
                    .unwrap();
                let device_extensions_supported =
                    device_extensions.iter().all(|device_extension| {
                        let device_extension = CStr::from_ptr(*device_extension);

                        supported_device_extensions.iter().any(|properties| {
                            CStr::from_ptr(properties.extension_name.as_ptr()) == device_extension
                        })
                    });

                if !device_extensions_supported {
                    return None;
                }

                let device_properties = instance.get_physical_device_properties(physical_device);
                Some((
                    physical_device,
                    queue_family,
                    format,
                    present_mode,
                    device_properties,
                ))
            })
            .max_by_key(|(_, _, _, _, properties)| match properties.device_type {
                vk::PhysicalDeviceType::DISCRETE_GPU => 2,
                vk::PhysicalDeviceType::INTEGRATED_GPU => 1,
                _ => 0,
            })
            .expect("No suitable physical device found");
            //end of declaration of enum (physical_device, queue_family, format, present_mode, device_properties)




    // https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Logical_device_and_queues
    let queue_info = vec![vk::DeviceQueueCreateInfoBuilder::new()
        .queue_family_index(queue_family)
        .queue_priorities(&[1.0])];

    let features = vk::PhysicalDeviceFeaturesBuilder::new();

    let device_info = vk::DeviceCreateInfoBuilder::new()
        .queue_create_infos(&queue_info)
        .enabled_features(&features)
        .enabled_extension_names(&device_extensions)
        .enabled_layer_names(&device_layers);


    let device =
        unsafe { DeviceLoader::new(&instance, physical_device, &device_info, None) }.unwrap();


    // let queue2 = unsafe { device2.get_device_queue(queue_family, 0) };
    let queue = unsafe { device.get_device_queue(queue_family, 0) };


    println!("\n \n");

    let model_path: &'static str = "assets/terrain__002__.obj";
    let (models, materials) = tobj::load_obj(&model_path, &tobj::LoadOptions::default()).expect("Failed to load model object!");
    let model = models[0].clone();
    let materials = materials.unwrap();
    let material = materials.clone().into_iter().nth(0).unwrap();
    let mut vertices = vec![];
    let mut indices = vec![];
    let mesh = model.mesh;
    let total_vertices_count = mesh.positions.len() / 3;
    for i in 0..total_vertices_count {
        let vertex = VertexV3 {
            pos: [
                mesh.positions[i * 3],
                mesh.positions[i * 3 + 1],
                mesh.positions[i * 3 + 2],
                1.0,
            ],
            color: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        };
        vertices.push(vertex);
    };
    indices = mesh.indices.clone();

    println!("Starting buffer and memory allocation/mapping processes... \n");


    let vertex_buffer_size = ::std::mem::size_of_val(&vertices) as vk::DeviceSize;
    
    println!("vertex_buffer_size: {:?}", vertex_buffer_size);

    let physical_device_memory_properties = unsafe { instance.get_physical_device_memory_properties(physical_device) };
    println!("\n physical_device_memory_properties: {:?}", physical_device_memory_properties);
    pretty_print(physical_device_memory_properties);


    let vertex_buffer_create_info = vk::BufferCreateInfoBuilder::new()
        .size(vertex_buffer_size * 8)
        .usage(vk::BufferUsageFlags::VERTEX_BUFFER)
        .sharing_mode(vk::SharingMode::EXCLUSIVE);

    println!("\n vertex_buffer_create_info: {:?}", vertex_buffer_create_info);

    let vertex_buffer = unsafe {
        device
            .create_buffer(&vertex_buffer_create_info, None)
            .expect("Failed to create vertex buffer.")
    };

    let vertex_buffer_memory_reqs = unsafe {
        device
            .get_buffer_memory_requirements(vertex_buffer)
    };
    println!("\n vertex_buffer_memory_reqs: {:?}", vertex_buffer_memory_reqs);

    let vertex_buffer_memory_allocate_info = unsafe {
        vk::MemoryAllocateInfoBuilder::new()
                    .allocation_size(vertex_buffer_memory_reqs.size)
                    .memory_type_index(2)
                    .build()
    };
    println!("\n vertex_buffer_memory_allocate_info, {:?} \n", vertex_buffer_memory_allocate_info);

    let vertex_buffer_memory = unsafe {
        device
            .allocate_memory(&vertex_buffer_memory_allocate_info, None)
            .expect("Failed to allocate vertex buffer memory.")
    };
    println!("\n vertex_buffer_memory: {:?} \n", &vertex_buffer_memory);

    unsafe { device.bind_buffer_memory(vertex_buffer, vertex_buffer_memory, 0) }
        .expect("Error on bind buffer memory");


    unsafe {
        let mut pointer: *mut *mut std::ffi::c_void = std::ptr::null_mut();

        device
            .map_memory(
                vertex_buffer_memory,
                0,
                vertex_buffer_memory_reqs.size,
                None,
                pointer,
            )
            .expect("failed to map 333memory.");

    }
}







fn pretty_print(stuff: vk::PhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties) {
    println!("\n pretty_print physical_device_memory_properties: \n");
    for memory_type in stuff.memory_types {
        println!("memory type: {:?}", memory_type);
    }
    for heap in stuff.memory_heaps {
        println!("memory heap: {:?}", heap);
    }

}
```

Comment: What memory type is your vertex buffer using? I don't see that part in your code, but if you e.g. create a device local buffer that's not accessible by the host, that may be the cause of your error.

Comment: Thank you for the comment (as well as the great tutorial postings).  Host-Visible and Host-Coherent selected memory type.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

With help from friz64 on the Erupt GameDev board:

I was derefencing a null pointer.
The pointer needed to be `*mut` rather than `*mut *mut`, and then take a mutable reference from it.
The block around `map_memory` should look like this:

```
    unsafe {
        let mut pointer: *mut std::ffi::c_void = std::ptr::null_mut();
        let mut ref1 = &mut pointer;
        device
            .map_memory(
                vertex_buffer_memory,
                256,
                vk::WHOLE_SIZE,
                None,
                ref1,
            )
            .expect("failed to map 333memory.");

    }
```